# Implicit conversion of TEXT to varchar/nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, text, varchar, nvarchar

I have a rather large historical table that is now slowing down my users.  One of the big things I did that will alleviate the issue is converting the text fields to nvarchar(max) or varchar(max) fields.  I am going with nvarchar because of Unicode/conversion issues that may arise.

My question is, will the front end, if declaring an explicit TEXT value, be implicitly converted when inserting into the table?

I am wondering as the fields are implicitly converted using an ALTER TABLE statement that I used for the initial conversion.

This table is used in rather a great many places and putting a CONVERT everywhere that its referenced will be problematical to say the least.

I tried testing this locally but local TEXT variables are not allowed when running locally.

Comment: Are you asking about _front end_? You didn't reveal anything about your front end...

Comment: Are you saying that your front end is executing sql that has a text variable in it?

Comment: No.  I am not asking about the front end.  The Front end MIGHT (I don't know yet) explicitly try to insert something into the table as TEXT.  Like a scan or an image file.  That's what this table is actually for, its all documents.  I am just wondering if there is an implicit conversion, or a way that I can force an implicit conversion just in case someone is explicitly trying to insert a declared text variable

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a cast?

```
CAST( @VARIABLEFROMFRONTEND as NVARCHAR(MAX) )
```

You can toss an if statement around it to check for an error before you allow it to attempt conversion. In case there is an error not really sure that would happen but worth having in there.

Comment: Yes I could.  BUt that is not really what I am looking for.  I am not the front end guy at my company and there would be a great deal of effort ensuring that this field is cast as a varchar.  I am trying to ascertain if there is an implicit conversion in SQL server for storing information there or will the team have to run through the code putting CAST everywhere.  ie.  Can a explicit Text field be stored in a nVarchar(max) field.